# ContentProvider Path Traversal Vulnerability

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Google warns about a path traversal vulnerability in ContentProvider
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7496913

> Implementations of `openFile` and `openAssetFile` in exported `ContentProviders` can be vulnerable if they do not properly validate incoming `Uri` parameters. A malicious app can supply a crafted `Uri` (for example, one that contains “/../”) to trick your app into returning a `ParcelFileDescriptor` for a file outside of the intended directory, thereby allowing the malicious app to access any file accessible to your app.

Their example (from the above link):

```
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile (Uri uri, String mode)
 throws FileNotFoundException {
 File f = new File(DIR, uri.getLastPathSegment());
  if (!f.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(DIR)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
 return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
}
```

What does the DIR refer to? How do i implement the correct fix?

Comment: have you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DIR` refers to the directory in your app's internal storage from which you want to share files.

This may be:

```
File fd = getContext().getFilesDir();
String DIR = fd.getAbsolutePath() + "/public";
```

(Result: `/data/user/0/[APPLICATION_ID]/files/public`)

**Fix:**

To fix the issue you must ensure, that an attacker can not access unexpected files in the internal storage by using a malicious URI which contains path traversal characters (e.g. "../").

(For example, your database file in `/data/user/0/[APPLICATION_ID]/databases` is a "unexpected file".)

As Google suggests, you can do this by checking the file’s canonical path. The canonical path is absolute and does not contain "." or ".." anymore. (If the canonical path of the file starts with your directory path, everything is fine.)

Example:

- Malicious URI: `content://[APPLICATION_ID]/public/../../databases/database.db`
- Malicious path: `/data/user/0/[APPLICATION_ID]/files/public/../../databases/database.db`
- Canonical path: `/data/user/0/[APPLICATION_ID]/databases/database.db`

So, here's the complete fix:

```
private String DIR; 

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    File fd = getContext().getFilesDir();
    DIR = fd.getAbsolutePath() + "/public";
    return true;
}

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File(DIR, uri.getLastPathSegment());
    if (!f.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(DIR)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
}
```

(Side note: `DIR` should be `dir`, because it's not a constant.)

Comment: Any tips/guide on how to test this vulnerability. i.e. testing Content provider to be specific.

Comment: I know no general approach to test this. It depends on your Content Provider implementation. (Google somehow is able to detect this vulnerability, but I don't know how it's done.) You could write a test that creates a file in the app's internal storage and uses a malicious URI to try to access it via your Content Provider. The test should expect IllegalArgumentException to succeed.

Comment: Thank. I have asked a completely different question. But your reply perfect response to the same. Yup doing the same what you test to pass and fail this test.